# Search Box Control in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Can anybody tell me how do i add search-box control in "XAML" windows phone 8?
i have tried for search-box control but seems that there is no such control exist.No such Namespace exist error shown by compiler..please suggest any answer thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`AutoCompleteBox`](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Auto_Complete_Box_in_Windows_Phone) which is a control works like a searchBox

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox  x:Name="txtSearch"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,22,3,10"  />
```